# Flask Login - is_authenticated and is_anonymous do not reflect sign in/sign out

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a Flask application and have recently implemented Flask-Login to my sign in/out forms:

```
@account.route('/sign-in', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sign_in():
    form = loginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data

        user = accounts.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if user is not None and user.verifyPassword(password):
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('main.index'))

    return render_template('signIn.html', form=form)


@account.route('/sign-out', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sign_out():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

After sign in, I suspect `current_user.is_authenticated` would be True and `current_user.is_anonymous` would be False and after sign out I would suspect `current_user.is_authenticated` would be False and then `current_user.is_anonymous` would be True.

However no matter if the user signs in `current_user.is_authenticated` and `current_user.is_anonymous` is always True. I though `login_user()` and `logout_user()` would change these values.

What is the issue and how can I return the right values? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us the `User` class?

Comment: @plaes Sure, just added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was such a simple one. Brackets much be used after using `is_authenticated` or `is_anonymous` such like:

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated() %}
  User is authenticated
{% endif %}
```

or

```
def view():
  if current_user.is_authenticated():
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed!

Comment: current_user.is_authenticated() in jinja results in an error of calling a bool object